# Drop empty tables in postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-drop

In my haste partition a rather large table, I created a simple sql script to create about 4,000 tables. now that things have calmed down, I can see that I have no use for most of the partitions as I have had zero inserts into them.

I now want to clean up those empty tables - how can I drop them using SQL? I believe I have part of the solution:

```
SELECT relname,n_live_tup
  FROM pg_stat_user_tables
  WHERE n_live_tup=0;
```

How do I chain that up with a `DROP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION drop_table(name TEXT)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE statement TEXT;
BEGIN
statement := 'DROP TABLE ' || name;
EXECUTE statement;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;

SELECT drop_table(relname)
FROM pg_stat_user_tables
WHERE n_live_tup = 0;
```

Comment: darn, i was hoping not to write a function... anyway, no luck - i get: ptolemy_production=> SELECT drop_table(relname)
ptolemy_production-> FROM pg_stat_user_tables
ptolemy_production-> WHERE n_live_tup = 0;
WARNING:  out of shared memory
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DROP TABLE spanning_tree__neighbour__vlan3801"
PL/pgSQL function drop_table(text) line 5 at EXECUTE statement
ERROR:  out of shared memory
HINT:  You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DROP TABLE spanning_tree__neighbour__vlan3801"
PL/pgSQL function drop_table(text) line 5 at EXECUTE statement

Comment: add `limit` to `select` or increase database settings (useful utility http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgtune/)

Comment: i'm accepting this answer, even tho in the end i just did a copy and paste of empty tables and parsed it with the `-f` flag on psql.